# Laravel pagination not working with join where condtion

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5

I am using laravel pagination for list. There is two tables lets say `table1` & `table2`.

`table2` `id` is primary key & used as foreign key in `table1` `t2_id`

I want to get all unique `t2_id` but need to check is_deleted is not set for that id in table2.

I have written function in my model:

```
public function getDistinctIds() {

    return DB::connection('pgsql')
                    ->table('table1 AS t1')
                    ->distinct()
                    ->select('t1.t2_id')
                    ->join('table2 AS t2', 't2.id', '=', 't1.t2_id')
                    ->where('t2.is_deleted', '!=', 1)
                    ->orWhereNull('t2.is_deleted')
                    ->paginate(3);
}
```

This function will give me accurate result. But there is problem with pagination. There are 12 records in `table1` `getDistinctIds()` gives only 4 record so there should be two pages but it is showing 4 pages. I think pagination is not taking where condition into consideration.

Please help thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is the table getDistinctIDs?Dump the query and run it on the db,you probably need a LEFT join or operator precedence messes your WHERE conditions

Comment: @Mihai getDistinctIDs is the funtion return in model. it is giving accurate result it return 4 rows so there should be 2 pages but instead it shows 4 pages links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution instead of `distinct()`used `groupBy()`. Now it is working fine. :)

Referenced from laracast post : [[L4.2] distinct() and pagination returns total number of results not distinct total](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l42-distinct-and-pagination-returns-total-number-of-results-not-distinct-total)